# electron title bar overlay adds white vertical lines when maximizing

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, electron

In my electron js project, I'm experiencing weird behaviour from the titlebar which is initialized with the following code:

```
function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
    titleBarOverlay: {
      color: '#1D1E20',
      symbolColor: '#EEEEEE'
    },
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      devTools: true
    },
    show: false
  })
  //win.webContents.openDevTools()
  win.loadFile('index.html')
  win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    win.show()
  })
}
```

When maximizing I get a vertical white line next to the maximize-Button, which I believe is because of the changing size of the native windows buttons when resizing.
Is there any way to solve this problem without styling a custom title bar?
[image: normal]
[image: maximized]